# I want to add image to post in FLASK, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, image, flask, web, post

I want to add image to post in `Flask`, but it doesn't work. I need to save the name of image to database (MySQL) and the image file to `UPLOAD_FOLDER` (`'static/images/uploads/'`). What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/add-post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            poster = current_user.id
            post = Posts(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, poster_id=poster, price=form.price.data, image=form.image.data, img_filename = img_filename, img_name=img_name, saver=saver)
            form.title.data = ''
            form.content.data = ''
            form.price.data = ''
            form.image.data = ''
            img_filename = secure_filename(form.image.data.filename)
            img_name = img_filename
            saver = request.files["image"]
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Succesfully posted")
        except:
            flash("Something went wrong")
    else:
        flash("Something went wrong")

    return render_template("add_post.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I solved the problem with this code:

```
# ADD_POST
@app.route('/add-post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()
    image_id = None
    if form.image.data:
        f = form.image.data
        image_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        file_name = image_id + '.png'
        file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file_name)
        Image.open(f).save(file_path)
    poster = current_user.id
    title = form.title.data
    category = form.category.data 
    content = form.content.data
    price = form.price.data
    post = Posts(poster_id=poster ,title=title,content=content,image=image_id, price=price, category=category)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Article posted')
    return render_template("add_post.html", form=form)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).